# custom tiles for route-me from my own bitmap?

Tags: ios, route-me

How do I create custom tiles for route-me from my own bitmap?
I know that map2sqlite is required, but where can I find a step by step tutorial?
Thanks, Colin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont give much details,
but http://www.mapnik.org 
might be a good place to start understand about how to generate tiles.